# Draw a circle using a plotter

Tags: java

I have a class called Circle that extends from a class called Shape. I am trying to figure out how to get a circle to draw on a plotter using the given description of the `draw()` method.

Here's what I have so far for the class:

```
public class Circle extends Shape{

    private double radius;

    public Circle(double x_origin, double y_origin, double r, Color c){
        super(x_origin, y_origin, c);
        this.radius = r;
    }

    public void draw(WinPlotter plotter){
        setPenColor(plotter);


    }

}
```

The setPenColor just provides a color for the circle to be drawn, feel free to ignore it.

The javadoc description for the circle's draw method is as follows:

> Draws the Circle. Uses sine and cosine functions from the
>   java.lang.Math class to compute a finite set of points that lie on the
>   circumference of a circle, and then uses the drawTo method of
>   WinPlotter to draw a sequence of small connected straight-line
>   segments. When enough segments are drawn (about 25 segments are
>   sufficient), a smooth circle is approximated.

If you need to see the entire Circle javadoc for it, [here it is](http://msoe.us/taylor/se1021/lab3doc/taylor/Circle.html#draw%28edu.msoe.se1010.winPlotter.WinPlotter%29)

Here is the [WinPlotter javadoc](https://faculty-web.msoe.edu/hornick/Courses/WinPlotter/doc/index.html) to use as a reference. I have only been using the `moveTo()` and `drawTo()` methods for every other shape I have had to draw.

I  just want to know the best way to draw a circle on the plotter.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way I can think of is to use `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` to loop to 360 degress(2*PI) over a set interval, drawing lines between the current value and the previous one.

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions and check out the pictures on the right. Then think about it as a loop with your loop variable being `thea`

GL on your homework.

*Edit*: Heres the link you should really look at http://iopixels.com/cos-sin-explain